# Efficient way to add a new key-value to a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a very large nested dictionary and below I am showing a sample of it.

```py
tmp_dict = {1: {'A': 1, 'B': 2},
            2: {'A': 0, 'B': 0}}
```

The question is what is any better/efficient way to add a new pair key value to my existing nested dict. I am currently looping through the keys to do so. Here is an example:

```py
>>> for k in tmp_dict.keys():
        tmp_dict[k].update({'C':1})
```

Comment: try using dict comprehension, ``{k: {**v, 'C' :1 } for k, v in tmp_dict.items()}``

Answer (score 1):

A simple method would be like so:

```py
for key in tmp_dict:
    tmp_dict[key]['C']=1
```

Or, you could use dictionary comprehension, as sushanth suggested

```py
tmp_dict = {k: {**v, 'C': 1} for k, v in timp_dict.items()}
```

You can read more about the asterisks (and why this works) [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/).

In terms of complexity, they are all O(N) time complexity (I think the dict comprehension maybe O(N^2)). So, your solution should have a relatively quick run time anyways.

Comment: The first part is the fastest way.  I believe the creation of a new dictionary outstrips the speed gains of the comprehension.